Shortest intervals that contain X rows
I have dataframe like this
data = {
  "timeStamp": ['06:00:00', '06:03:00', '06:10:00', '06:30:00', '06:32:00', '06:02:00', '06:05:00', '06:06:00', '06:55:00', '06:00:00', '06:01:00', '06:20:00', '07:00:00'],
  "Event": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I need to know shortest intervals that contain 3 or more rows by each group.
In given example we see:

that during event "A" shortest interval with 3 rows is 10 minutes (from 06:00:00 to 06:10:00)
during event "B" shortest interval with 3 rows is 4 minutes (from 06:02:00 to 06:06:00)
during event "C" shortest interval with 3 rows is 20 minutes (from 06:00:00 to 06:20:00)
there are no such intervals during event "D"

Desired output looks like



Event
Interval




A
00:10:00


B
00:04:00


C
00:20:00


D
NA



...
etc
Is there any elegant way to do this?

Pls explain better your logic. Interval between which events?

Please clearly explain the logic. Also provide the exact expected output given your small example.

Are your intervals defined a certain way, e.g. regular interval of 2 minutes ? Maybe this can help you ?

I'm sorry for the mess in first version of question. Now I've tried better explain what I need to get.

You can groupby("Event") and then apply a custom aggregation function.
# Convert to datetime to compute intervals
df['timeStamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timeStamp'])

def find_shortest_interval_3(group):
    if len(group) < 3:
        return None
    
    group = group.sort_values('timeStamp')
    min_interval = pd.Timedelta.max
    for i in range(len(group) - 2): # You can parameterize this so that its not always 3
        current_interval = group.iloc[i+2]['timeStamp'] - group.iloc[i]['timeStamp']
        if current_interval < min_interval:
            min_interval = current_interval
    return min_interval

print(df.groupby('Event').apply(find_shortest_interval_3))

Output:
Event
A   0 days 00:10:00
B   0 days 00:04:00
C   0 days 00:20:00
D               NaT

